# Ajax method submit() is not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, submit

**Here is the code.**

```
var r = confirm("Submit the form?");
if (r==true) {
                 ('#cat_add').on('submit', function(e) {
                $.post("Process.php", $(this).serialize());
                });
             }
```

When the user clicks "yes" nothing happens.

Comment: Hit F12, go to console. What is the error?

Comment: add in the $ or Jquery on  $('#cat_add').on()

Answer (score 1):

You need some code to submit the form for you when they confirm that they want to submit it. Then you need to stop the form from refreshing the page when the form is submitted.

You are also missing a `$` in your `('#cat_add').on('submit')`.

```
if(r) {
    $('#cat_add').submit();
}

//This should go outside of the if statement
$('#cat_add').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("Process.php", $(this).serialize());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click', '#cat_submit', function(){
  var form_data = $('#cat_add').serialize();
  var r = confirm("Submit the form?");  
  if (r==true) {
    console.log("it works!");
      $.post("Process.php", form_data);
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<form id="cat_add">
  <input type="text" name="cat_name" />
  <input id="cat_submit" type="button" value="submit" />
</form>
```